# HTML input type=file - strange behaviour on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-file

I have a `input type=file` which works correctly on Chrome but when I am trying it on Internet Explorer 9, clicking on the button do not work but then if I refresh the page it will work. And if i try again after that, it will not work anymore....

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
               Browse <input type="file" id="inputLogo" />
          </span>
     </span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly ng-model="logoName" id="logoName" />
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER (ANGULARJS)**

```
$("#inputLogo").fileReader({
    filereader: "js/lib/FileReader/filereader.swf"
});

$("#inputLogo").on('change', function (e) {
    var image = e.target.files[0];
    console.log("IMAGE:" + image);
    $scope.logoName = image.name;
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.onload = function (e) {
        var custLogo = e.target.result;
        while (custLogo.charAt(0) != "4") {
            custLogo = custLogo.substr(1);
        }
        custLogo = custLogo.substr(1);
        custLogo = custLogo.substr(1);
        $scope.logoBase64 = custLogo;
    }
    filereader.readAsDataURL(image);
});
```

**EDIT**
When I click on the "browse" button nothing happens. No dialog pop-up, no console errors.
Everything works well on another page. 
The only difference I see between those two is that on the buggy one my input is in a table row and the table is inside a `ng-show` (angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

If the second time you try, you choose the same file, the change event isn't triggered because the value doesn't change. You have to reset the input value after the first time :

```
e.target.value = '';
```

Comment: The first time I try, it does not work. I have to refresh the page to make it work

Comment: What does not work ? The file browser window opens ? FileReader API isn't supported by IE 9 so maybe your polyfill using Flash swf is buggy. No errors in console ?

Comment: When I click on the "Browse" button, nothing happend : No window opened, no errors in console. Evertyhing is OK in Chrome... but not IE. The FileReader that I use is a different one. It's library javascript+flash

Comment: Yes the FileReader isn't the problem if the browser window doesn't open. Have you a specific CSS on your input file ? The click event on the input is triggered ?

Comment: I edited my post to make it clearer ;) I tried a simple input file without css

Comment: Have you try a ng-click on the input and console.log if the click event is triggered ?

Comment: I put the input outside my table and it works perfectly... So it's link either to the table or to the ng-show....